# Click event not working on loaded html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I see that live is deprecated so I used .on() but nothing happens when I click on my link which is within the loaded html:

```
$('.playclose').on("click", function() {
        alert('hello');
        });
```

any ideas?

Comment: where is the rest of your code? are you using the right jquery version? at least have the html of playclose

Comment: Please add HTML codes as well. It's easier for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $(document).on("click",'.playclose', function() {
            alert('hello');
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.playclose', function() {
 alert('hello');
});
```

The syntax for delegate event (aka live) is like:

`$('static-container-selector').on( event, target, handler);`

**NOTE**

Instead of `body` or `document` its better to use any other static container ie. non-dynamic element and also check that `playclose` is `id` or `class`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the button is using a class and not an id?

Your selector may be wrong.

$('#playclose') insteead of $('.playclose')

Answer (score 0):

[Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

For delegated elements we need to use like as follows

```
$(document).on("click",'.playclose', function() {
            alert('hello');
   });
```